# Can a VB6 project use a .Net .dll

Tags: .net, vb6, asp-classic, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 project.  My question is can I call a .NET .dll that has all the business rules of the project (from the VB6 application)?

Basically I have a VB6 project with a classic ASP project calling a vb6/ActiveX .dll.  The requirement is to figure out the best way to upgrade the application.  So, if I update the ActiveX .dll can the VB6 app call that new .NET .dll?

I guess the same question is viable for the classic ASP project as well...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you need to make the .Net types Com Visible.
Also see Matt's comment below regarding array indices and strings.
The fact that it's possible doesn't make it a good idea though...

Comment: Sounds like this might be a good idea in this case.  Start by upgrading business logic in a new .NET dll.  Then upgrade another piece etc until you rewrite the gui.

Comment: Gotta agree. Unless the project is just really really big, it's likely going to be more work to create a Vb6 callable .net lib that it would be to port things to .net and move forward. Migrating peicemeal always +sounds+ great, but it's usually not worth it unless the project size is quite large.

Comment: +1 - There are some other considerations to bear in mind. Like 1 based arrays in VB6 compared with 0 based arrays in .NET. Fixed length string are not fully supported in .NET and data types are different sizes for the same type (VB6 Long = .NET Int32)

Comment: but what if you're migrating a dll and you want to keep the client app untouched (without recompile)?

Comment: Maybe this can help [Exposing-Class-Members-from-NET-to-Visual-Basic-6](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/380403/Exposing-Class-Members-from-NET-to-Visual-Basic-6)