# Use vb6 functions in C# project

Tags: c#, vb6, vb6-migration

I have many functions that was written with vb6.
 
I searched  on the net and I found this way:

```
[DllImport("C:/MyDll.dll")] .....
```

But an error message was displaying saying  :

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'theMethode' in DLL 'C:/MyDll.dll'.
```

My question is, is there a solution do this.
 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please post one of these methods, at least?

Comment: Is there a method called `theMethode` in that DLL?  Are you really keeping the DLL in the root of `C:`?

Comment: Is your method COM visible?  If not, the accepted answer on this question may be beneficial:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721071/can-a-vb6-project-use-a-net-dll

Comment: You need to use `.net Interop` to integrate vb6 code. Basically, set reference to your vb6 library and it will create .net interop assembly.

Comment: no but there is no methode called themethode, but just to explian my sutuation, I wrote this code.

this is the vb6 code 
Public Function blankString() As String
    blankString = ""
End Function


and in c#:
[DllImport("C:/dlls/Vb6toCsharp/MyDll3.dll")]
        public static extern string blankString();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String ch ;
            ch = "sdfns";
            MessageBox.Show(ch+"");
            ch = blankString();
            MessageBox.Show(ch+"");
        }

Comment: Another method: Copy/paste your code into .net files. It should be little effort to convert since .net supports all those vb6 functions in .net way

Answer (score 2):

The answer for using non-.net assembles is to use `Interop`. Microsoft designed it specifically for this purpose.

Comment: thanks, if you mean that I have yo add `using System.Runtime.InteropServices; `, I have already write it.

Comment: Try to add reference in your .net project to a vb6 dll - you'll see

Comment: I still have the same problem .

Comment: I think that the problem is in the dll which I built with vb6(Activex dll), because when I used an other dll, it works correctly. So I will check the dll sctructure and see if there is any problem.  Thanks

Comment: Is the DLL registered? "regsvr32 dllname.dll"

Comment: As I thought, the problem was in the dll (built with vb6).
now evry think is ok.
thanks fot evryboby.